# Limit to the Subscription of the Topics

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Is there a limit to the Subscription of the Topics in Azure Service Bus?

I will create a subscription for each TenantID, has a problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and it is 2000 for per topic.

You can check [limitations](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/)